# Confirm Email Address before Submitting AJAX Form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form that I'm submitting through AJAX. The form includes many fields, but the two I'm having trouble with are "emailaddress" and "confirmemailaddress". I'd like it if the form could only be submitted if the these two fields are identical. The caveat is that these two forms are also not required. So if they are both blank, they should be able to submit just fine.

Here's the code I am working with thus far. I've removed a lot of the visual effects that happen during and after the form submits to keep it clean.

```
$(function() {

  $("#contact_form form").submit(function() {
    var thistarget = this.target;

    $("#contact_form form").validate({
    rules: {
        emailaddress: "required",
        confirmemailaddress: {
        equalTo: "#emailaddress"
           }
         }
    });
   return false;  

  $.ajax({  

      type: this.method, 
      url: this.action,  
      data: $(this).serialize(), 

      success: function() {  
        alert ("success:");

        $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
        $('#message').html("<h2>Request Form Submitted!</h2>")  
        .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")  
        .hide()  
        .fadeIn(1500, function() {  
          $('#message').append("Thank you!");  
        }); 

      }


    });

   return false;  

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete: emailaddress: "required", if you have that rule you won't be able to submit the form unless you input an email address.

Comment: Email address is completely optional. They can give me no email, but if they do give an email, I want to make sure it's right.

Comment: That's why I told you to just delete the required part of the rule. Because if you say a field is required then you can't leave it blank.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of validator use below code..

```
if( $('#emailaddress').val() == $('#confirmemailaddress').val() ) 
{
do ajax code
}else{
return false;
}
```